# XQuery comparing variables as numbers

Tags: xquery

I want to produce an XQuery that outputs the price of three CDs, less the price of the cheapest CD. I have produced a user defined function sumtwomax() which takes three integer parameters and produces the sum of the largest two numbers. This works when I supply it with numbers. 
But I have a problem when supplying it with variables from a FLWOR expression. Could someone please help me with this?

Here is my XML code:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <code>c002</code>
    <price>10</price>
    <rating>5</rating>
  </item>
  <item>
    <code>c006</code>
    <price>15</price>
    <rating>3</rating>
  </item>
  <item>
    <code>c004</code>
    <price>12</price>
    <rating>3</rating>
  </item>
  <item>
    <code>c001</code>
    <price>7</price>
    <rating>5</rating>
  </item>
  <item>
    <code>c003</code>
    <price>10</price>
    <rating>4</rating>
  </item>
  <item>
    <code>c005</code>
    <price>8</price>
    <rating>4</rating>
  </item>
</items>
```

And here is my XQuery:

```
declare namespace myfn = "http://www.brookes.ac.uk/P00601/xquery/functions";
declare function myfn:sumtwomax( $first,  $sec, $third)  { sum(($first, $sec, $third)) - min (($first, $sec, $third))};

for $d in doc("shop.xml") //item
let $price1 := xs:integer($d/price/data()[$d/code="c002"]) 
let $price2 := xs:integer($d/price/data()[$d/code="c004"]) 
let $price3 := xs:integer($d/price/data()[$d/code="c006"])
return
myfn:sumtwomax($price1, $price2, $price3)
```

This produces '0 0 0' as a result, instead of the desired value '15'. Could someone please help with this?

Comment: StackSnippets are for code that can run inside the browser. Use `{}` for regular code formatting.

Comment: ...and btw, consider writing this as a single document with a context item -- that way people don't need to actually create a separate `shop.xml` to be able to run the query. See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/909cb01c6affdb2149a901299f26243d for this question's code as a single standalone XQuery instance.

Comment: ...that said, the bigger issue here is that the code in this question should be a [mcve] -- the *simplest possible* thing that produces the same problem. For instance, if you can create the same problem with `let $price1 := xs:integer("10")`, then you *should* do that, and leave `shop.xml` out of the question entirely. And if you *can't* create the problem, then you could just ask how `xs:integer("10")` and `xs:integer($d/price/data()[$d/code="c002"])` are different, and not need to include `sumtwomax` in the question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FLWOR expression doesn't make any sense in this context: It's only evaluating a single `item` at a time (and `return`ing one result per `item`), but the expressions you run inside that loop only return useful results if they can search through *all* the items, to be able to fill out all three variables (as opposed to only the variable associated with the single item being iterated over by the loop at that time).

Consider instead iterating over `items` elements (of which there's only one), if you *really* want to make this a FLWOR:

```
declare function myfn:sumtwomax( $first,  $sec, $third)  { sum(($first, $sec, $third)) - min (($first, $sec, $third))};

for $d in //items
let $price1 := xs:integer($d/item[code="c002"]/price)
let $price2 := xs:integer($d/item[code="c004"]/price) 
let $price3 := xs:integer($d/item[code="c006"]/price)
return myfn:sumtwomax($price1, $price2, $price3)
```

...or, removing the needless `for` entirely:

```
declare function myfn:sumtwomax( $first,  $sec, $third)  { sum(($first, $sec, $third)) - min (($first, $sec, $third))};

let $price1 := xs:integer(//item[code="c002"]/price)
let $price2 := xs:integer(//item[code="c004"]/price) 
let $price3 := xs:integer(//item[code="c006"]/price)
return myfn:sumtwomax($price1, $price2, $price3)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and sorry for the needless text. Could you explain how `xs:integer(//item[code="c002"]/price)` is different from `xs:integer(//item/price/data()[//item/code="c002"])` ?

Comment: `//item[code="c002"]/price` can be thought of as finding *all* items, filtering for only those with `code="c002"`, and then taking the `price` of the remainder. By contrast, `//item/price/data()[//item/code="c002"]` is taking *all* `//item/price/data()` items, and then filter for those where `//item/code="c002"` is true. However, `//item` is looking at *all `item`s in the document*, not the specific item for which you've already selected the `price` element's data, so this filter expression frankly makes very little sense.